# Attach invoice PDF in invoice email

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, email-attachments

I am trying to find a way to attach the default invoice Pdf file in the invoice Mail. 
I've found some tryouts on this issue but nothing of them worked.

Currently i tried this tutorial: http://www.ericpan.com/2013/02/14/add-pdf-attachment-to-invoice-email/#.VOS44Xa6ab4

Do you have any ideas regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this free module (see description): http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/email-attachments-by-fooman.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already checked this. I think my problem is to attach the Symmetrics PDF file not the default file. And i don't know how to do it! .. Anyway thanks.